# Publishing a Unity3d artifact in Nexus repository

Tags: java, android, maven, jenkins, nexus

I'm new in Maven and my goal is to publish an APK in a repository like (Nexus). This APK is built in Jenkins with Unity3dBuilder plugin. My job in jenkins is a maven2/3 project, so I need to configure my pom.xml so that I can publish my artifact (apk).

How can I add my artifact (generated by Unity) to my pom.xml ? it is a dependency or an attach-artifact ? what is the maven plugin that can do this action ?

Any help please !!??

Answer (score 0):

The Maven Deploy Plugin does the publishing. If the projects is a Maven project the default artifact will automatically be published if you have things configured.

Depending how you invoke the Unity3dBuilder (I know nothing about it) the output might have to be attached as an artifact with the build helper Maven plugin.